# Displaying date in nvd3 multichart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to display dates on a nvd3 Graph. I've done this successfully using the lineChart model but am struggling with the multiChart model.

The graph displays correctly, but I just can get the x axis labels to work. From what I can see this is because the value of d passed tickFormat is NaN, I'm not sure why.

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(d)
```

This means I can't get the value to create a d3.time.format from.

However after the chart is drawn the value of d is what I'd expect ( it's the return value of the chart.x function ).

```
var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
.x(function(data,increment){
    return data.x
});
```

I'm  a little bit over my head with this, trying to understand the nv source code, but how this all hangs together isn't intuitive to me yet!

Any help advice would as always be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 0):

As my personal experience, it seems like the date in XAxis changed into timestamp number.
Try this

```
chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d));
});
```